# Using splice() in a LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

In Aura you needed to set the component after using splice(). In the LWC js, I'm not sure to handle this.

```
        this.subLineItems.forEach(function(item, index, object) {
            if (item.Name !== subName) {
                object.splice(index, 1)
            }
        });
```

I want to remove certain objects from the array, then return the updated array.

Comment: In most programming language you can't alter the array you creating iterating into. Are you using ' @api' or '@track' on subLineItems?

Comment: i'm using @track

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how sensitive it is but if you're tracking your variable simply changing it should allow for it to rerender.

If removing or adding elements isn't enough, you could construct a new array sans the unwanted item and then assign the array to your tracked variable.

```
@track myArray;
@track subName;

handleClick(event) {
    let newArray = [];


    /* If you're dumb like me this is what your JS might look like
    this.myArray.forEach(function(item, index, object){
        if (item.Name !== this.subName) {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    }, this);
    */

    // or you could try the filter method
    this.myArray = this.myArray.filter(function(element) {
        return element.Name === this.subName;
    }, this);

    this.myArray = newArray;
}
```

### Disclaimer

I'm not an expert on LWC and I'm not in a position to test, this is just an instinctual answer based on minimal experience.

Comment: Thanks for this, with a few tweaks I was able to get it working.

Comment: That is good, please dont forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @gNerb your example has errors which you may want to correct: 1. you comparing against subName but you mean this.subName, 2.you push to this.newArray but the local defined newArray.




Pete for your Use case you can also use a filter function to remove items e. g. like this: this.subLineItems = this.subLineItems.filter(item => item.Name !== this.subName); Example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/bBvLMx-xA/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it very quickly. My war against JavaScript as me under-educated in the features thereof. I didn't know about the filter method, thanks for the info.

Comment: The filter works well, thanks for the example @Renji-xD